# Reordering admin columns for CPT with custom taxonomy and an added custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

This may be a repeat but it's the combination of things I can't find.

Custom post type is `event`.

I have added an admin column 'Event Date' generated by ACF and it appears at the right. Everything appears fine in this order; 'Title', 'Venue', 'Date' 'Event Date'

I'd like to reorder it. So far so good, this code does that.

But the custom taxonomy 'venue' which has the slug `venue` does not reappear (it appears but is not populated). How do I find out what the custom taxonomy is called for the purposes of the admin columns?

```
function reorder_event_columns( $columns ) {

$columns = array(
    'cb' => $columns['cb'],
    'title' => __( 'Title' ),  // Post Title
    'venue' => __( 'Venue'), // not populated!
    'event_date' => __( 'Start Date'), // Appears fine
    'date' => __('Date'), // Published Date
);

  return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'manage_event_posts_columns', 'reorder_event_columns' );
```

Answer (score 1):

As ever, simple when you know.

Custom taxonomy columns in admin are called 'taxonomy-venue' if 'venue' is the taxonomy slug

So I now have my columns in the right order and even the custom taxonomy and acf sortable. Bliss.